# Find density of X - x coordinate of randomly chosen point in the unit circle

Tags: probability

Given is the unit circle in the plane. Choose randomly point in it, such that $P(\left(x,y\right)\in A)$ is proportional to area of $A$, where $A$ is measurable set in plane. Find density function of random variable $X$ which represents the $x$ coordinate of this point.

My idea was to find $P(X\leq x)$ and then differentiate, but I'm struggling with determining area of subset of a circle where all x-coordinates are less or equal to given $x$ while $x$ varies in $\left[-1,1\right]$. Attached is the figure for fixed $x$.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to find the marginal density directly. For each $-1<x<1$,
we have 
$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy=
\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1\over \pi}\,dy=
{2\sqrt{1-x^2}\over \pi},$$
that is, $f_X(x)$ is the length of the slice at $x$ 
divided by the area of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, if you do not integrate, then from the surface of the unit circle subtract the area of ​​a circle segment a radius of 1 and a angle $\alpha$:

[image]

$A=\pi-\left(\frac{1^2}{2}\cdot 2\alpha-x\cdot y\right)=\pi-\arccos x+x\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow P(X\le x)=\frac{1}{\pi}(\pi-\arccos x+x\sqrt{1-x^2})$